# Question about results of intersecting planes in vector form

Tags: linear-algebra

Look at solution 6 of this (this isn't my homework or anything):
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Vectors_in_Space/Solutions

I was attempting to solve this and mistakenly thought that the intersection of the two planes would be the general solution after using Gauss's method on the two planes, but I was wrong. They just substituted the solution for K back into the second plane which I sort of understand.

My real issue is not the way the solution was solved, I get that now, but...

What does the general solution in this context actually mean? Because you can still find a general solution, but it's not the intersection of the two planes, and after looking at it now it would be 4 dimensional (I think?)
By general solution I mean this:

```
|1   | + |2  |
|-1/3| + |2/3| * m | m all real numbers 
|-1/9| + |8/9|
|0   | + |1  |
```

Seriously struggling with this, I've tried graphing it out on geogrebra but I am not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "the general solution".

A plane, in 3 dimensional space, has dimension 2.  The intersection of two such planes has dimension 2- 1= 1, a line.p

In problem 6, one plane is defined by
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}t+ \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}s$ so x= t, y= t+ s, z= t+ 3s.

The other plane is defined by
$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}k+ \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}u$
so x= 1+ 2u, y= 1+ 3k, z= 4u.

At any point of intersection, x= t= 1+ 2u, y= t+ s= 1+ 3k, z= t+ 3s= 4u.

That is three equations in four unknowns so we can solve for three of them in terms of the fourth- the parameter for the line.  The first equation is t= 1+ 2u so the second equation can be written as 1+ 2u+ s= 1+ 3k or 3k= 2u+ s.  The fourth equation can be written as 1+ 2u+ 3s=4u so 2u= 3s+ 2 or u= (3/2)s+ 1.  Then 3k= 3s+ 2+ s= 4s+ 2, k= (4/3)s+ 2/3.  t= 1+ 2u= 1+ 3s+ 2= 3s+ 3.

So, x= 3s+ 3, y= 1+ 4s+ 2= 4s+ 1, z= 4u= 6s+ 4.

That can also be written as
$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 4 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}s+ \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I appreciate that, I think that makes sense. I'm new to Linear Algebra and I keep forgetting what the actual numbers and definitions mean. I've been learning solely through reading the textbook online and I think I need a more visual approach to it